# Error With Assembly references in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, compilation

The problem is that my `System.Data.SQLite` And `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPack` assembly reference has an exclamation mark beside it, and when I try to click it, it says:

> This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is
>   unavailable or not yet built. Please ensure that the project is
>   available and built.

I recently started to learn assembly in order to do reverse engineering
How do I get my assembly references to work?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove reference `dll(System.Data.SQLite,Microsoft.VisualBasic)` then add again same reference dll. It may be reference wrong path.